# Extjs 4 Grid removing filter after few seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, filter

I am filtering data from server side proxy : 
`id: 'projectStore',
model: 'project',
remoteSort: true,
remoteFilter: true,
autoLoad: true,
autoSync: true,
proxy: {
       type: 'rest',
       url: 'app/projects.php',
       reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'projects'
         }
      }`

this is my filter code :
`projectStore.clearFilter();
            var comboArray = [
                  Ext.getCmp('projectCombo').getValue(),
                  Ext.getCmp('statusCombo').getValue(),
                  Ext.getCmp('typologyCombo').getValue(),
                  Ext.getCmp('donorCombo').getValue(),
                  Ext.getCmp('programCombo').getValue(),
                  Ext.getCmp('regionCombo').getRawValue(),
                  Ext.getCmp('cityCombo').getRawValue()
                ];
    if (comboArray[0] != "All" && comboArray[0] != 'default combo value') {
              projectStore.filter('PRJ_TYPE', comboArray[0]);
            }
    if (comboArray[1] != "All" && comboArray[1] != 'default combo value') {
              projectStore.filter('PRJ_STATUS', comboArray[1]);
            }`

                   ... And so on, 
when I **EXTJS** sends request to server, server response is correct and grid is loading filtered data for about 2-3 seconds then it becomes unfiltered again! I need it to be filtered until I will clear filter myself, I have tried many things but couldn't find solution for that.
 thank you in advance!

Comment: maybe you should be remove autoSync: true. Can you write code more details?

Answer (score 0):

These are the symptoms of a race condition.

Since your store is configured as autoLoad, it gets loaded unfilteted when the store is instantiated. Then immediately you filter it. If the store's unfiltered load takes a few seconds  longer than the filtered load, you will get what you describe.

The solution is to set autoLoad to false and to load the store manually ( if it doesn't already load automatically when you apply the filter ).

Comment: when you say load store manually, do you mean to load store when certain even is fired or send ajax requests myself?

Comment: I mean just call `store.load()` in the code after adding the filter.